# What's the range of a maxed out pyramid with six beacon in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm planning a massive floating base and trying to figure out the dimensions to make it so that a six beaconed pyramid covers the entire base. Does anyone happen to know the range of a four layered pyramid with six beacons on it?

Comment: The "beacon" page of the Minecraft wiki has a paragraph titled "range". It's not really hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

The range of the maxed out beacon is 50 blocks, as said here on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon#Range)
but the range of 6 beacons depends on your arrangement.
If you have your beacons in a 2*3 rectangle on the pyramid (cheapest), the range would be 102*103 respectively, but you could use multiple effects that would all be present in 98*96 respectively.
For a 1*6 orientation, it would be 101*106 respectively and for all, it would be 101*90 respectively.